# ggplot -> create negative x value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot traces with ggplot, using geom_path().

The origin of the coordinate system is in the middle. Both, x and y have positive and negative values.

I didn´t find any plot, which shows negative x values.

Is it possible to plot this with R?

Comment: Take a look at some of the other questions under the [tag:ggplot2] tag and update your question accordingly. Otherwise you will sadly attract downvotes and the question *will* get closed. The [**about**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [**FAQ**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) sections of the website will help you get the most out of the site.

Comment: Suggesting closure since no data presented and the question lacks clarity of desired outcome.

Answer (score 2):

Umm, I mgiht be missing something due to the incompleteness of the question, but ggplot and geom_path() have no problems at all working with negative data.

For example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)

myear <- ddply(movies, .(year), colwise(mean, .(length, rating)))
myear$lengthc <- myear$length - mean(myear$length)
myear$ratingc <- myear$rating - mean(myear$rating)
summary(myear)

p <- ggplot(myear, aes(lengthc, ratingc))
p + geom_path()
```

I just mean centered both variables from the geom_path() example (so they both have positive and negative values), and the plot looks as expected.